# cannot figure out how to add method to resource laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

I'm trying to add methods to my resource in laravel 5.6. This is my web.php file:

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/results', 'StudentsController@results');
Route::resource('student', 'StudentsController');
```

and here is (the important part) of my controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        return view('search');
    }

    public function results()
    {
        $search = \Request::get('search');

        $results = Student::where('last_name','like','%'.$search.'%')->get();

        return view('results')->with('results', $results);

    }
```

I'm trying to call the "results" function in the action on a form by doing {{route('student.results')}} but it's returning an eternal error of

```
Route [student.results] not defined.
```

I can do this exact syntax with all the other default crud functions in the controller. What am I doing wrong so that I can't call this new function. I have a feeling it's the wording of my route but I couldn't find anything that showed me exactly what to do. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You must define the route name:

```
Route::get('/results', ['as'=>'student.results', 'uses'=>'StudentsController@results']);
```

You need to do this for every manually defined routes. Resource routes are automatically named by Laravel.

Comment: Oh ok. That's completely different than anything I thought I had to do. I'm going to do it your way, but just out of curiosity, is there a non-associative array way to do it?